# Como chamo um metodo de uma classe do tipo QtGui.QMainWindow, dentro de outra classe do tipo QObject em python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Tenho uma classe:

```
class MyWindow2Class(QtGui.QMainWindow, form2_class):
```

dentro do `init` dela tenho esse trecho de código:

```
self.scr = ScriptManager(self)
self.qwebview.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("obj", self.scr)
self.qwebview.load(QtCore.QUrl('pagina.html'))
self.btnEnviar.clicked.connect(self.btnEnviar_clicked)
```

E tenho o seguinte método:

```
def btnEnviar_clicked(self):
```

No *javascript* da pagina eu chamo

```
obj.Enviar();
```

E na classe *ScriptManager* tem um método

```
def Enviar(self):
```

Como faço pra que o método *Enviar* nessa classe *ScriptManager* chame o `btnEnviar_clicked`, quando o javascript chamar o objeto..

Eu testei e se eu der um *print* por exemplo na classe *Enviar*, funciona direitinho, mas eu não descobri como chamar um método dentro da classe pai..
Tentei o `super(ScriptManager, self).btnEnviar_clicked()`
Mas dá erro e não funciona..

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver..
Foi so criar a classe dentro da classe, e usar uma funcao qualquer para iniciar e mandar o parent pra dentro da subclasse :) resolvido

Comment: Poste parte do código que resolveu o problema, assim você estará colaborando para futuras pesquisas!